# Hibernate getCurrentSession behavior with async servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

The internals of the Servlet 3.0 async api specify that the servlets are handled by a multiplexor pool of threads. What is the behavior of getCurrentSession with this? Will it leave the session open until the multiplexor thread is destroyed due to idleness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet requests have always been handled by a thread pools, so that Servlet 3.0 doesn't introduce anything new here. Thread-bound `Session`s obtained from `getCurrentSession()` get closed (by default) after transaction commit, therefore you shouldn't have any problems with thread pools as long as you correctly implement transaction management.

The new thing in Servlet 3.0 is that different phases of async request processing can be handled by different threads, therefore you cannot use thread-bound `Session` throughout these phases. However, you can still use thread-bound `Session` inside a single processing phase.

Also async processing poses a problem for Open Session in View pattern.

However, all these problems don't matter as long as you don't use async API.